# MongoDB based data is not populating in Chart.js

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, chart.js

i'm trying to make multiple charts that display results to survey questions. all i see are empty charts on screen with the message [object Object] appearing on each chart. data transmission from backend to frontend seems fine via App.js' console.log. my question is: is my problem occurring with the input data itself (eg data structure) or processing step for chart population? any advice appreciated tia

App.js

```
export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      chartData: []
    };
  }
 
  componentDidMount() {
    this.getChartData();
  }

  getChartData() {
    axios
      .get(`/getData`)
      .then(res => {
        const x = res.data;
        console.log(x);
        let chartData = [];
        x.forEach(element => {
          chartData.push({
            labels: element.answer_set,
            datasets:[{
              data: element.count_set
            }]
          });
        });
        this.setState({chartData});
      })
  }

  render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <Bar data={this.state.chartData} />
          </div>
        );
  }
```

data structure via console.log(x) in App.js

```
[
  {
    _id: question1,

    answer_set: [
      {answer: "answer1"},
      {answer: "answer2"}
    ],

    count_set: [
      {count: "countForAnswer1"},
      {count: "countForAnswer2"}
    ]
  },
    
  {
    _id: question2, ....  
]
```

Comment: The JSON data looks weird, as if instead of 
`answer_set: [
      {
        answer: "answer1",
        answer: "answer2"
      }
    ]`
it must be
`answer_set: [
      {
        answer: "answer1"
      },
      {
        answer: "answer2"
      }
    ]`.
Same structure also for the `count_set`.

Comment: @Nazim thx, updated above to correct this typo

Answer (score 0):

Value for `data` property when dealing with datasets should have the following shape

```
PropTypes.shape({
  datasets: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({
    data: PropTypes.array
  }))
})
```

[For example,](https://github.com/jerairrest/react-chartjs-2/blob/c96d9408ad26ccf40d56d72e8c894b6e1ad90bfa/example/src/components/bar.js#L5)

```
    {
            datasets: [
              {
                _id: '238940890234809234',
                data: [10, 20, 10, 20, 10, 20, 10]
              },
              {
                _id: '098340598345839455',
                data: [50, 100, 50, 100, 50, 100, 50]
              }
            ]
   }
```

You have to plot a different bar graph for each question.

```
  render() {
        return (
          <div>
            {this.state.chartData.map(data => <Bar key={data._id} data={data} /> }
          </div>
        );
  }
```

The _id has been included to be used for the component key property.

```js
chartData.push({
  _id: element._id,
  labels: element.answer_set,
  datasets:[{
    data: element.count_set
  }]
});
```